# How to close specified warning in C source code?

Tags: c, gcc, compile-time

For example, how can I get rid of "`warning: unnamed struct/union that defines no instances`" in the source file, not through compiler command-line options.

I want to define a C macro  `CONST_BUG_ON`, which I use to check some const values at compile time.

```
#define CONST_BUG_ON(e)        struct  {int a:!(e);}
```

It gives the warning `warning: unnamed struct/union that defines no instances`, but in this case it is not a real problem.

Thanks Tom Tanner

```
#define CONST_BUG_ON_3(e, l) struct buggy##l {int a:!(e);}
#define CONST_BUG_ON_2(e, l) CONST_BUG_ON_3(e, l)
#define CONST_BUG_ON(e) CONST_BUG_ON_2(e, __LINE__)
```

That's good, but still have some problems: If file `a`'s line 6 contain CONST_BUG_ON(e), and file `a` was inclued by file `b`, and line 6 of file `b` aslo contains CONST_BUG_ON(e), then gcc complains redefine error. Use`__COUNTER__` instade of `__LINE__` may perfect, but my old compiler does not support `__COUNTER__`.

Thanks Basile Starynkevitch

```
#define CONST_BUG_ON(e) do { \
   int tab[__builtin_constant_p(e)?1:-1] = {0}; \
   if (tab[0]) abort(); } while (0)
```

This is a C statement, can only be place in a function, I really want to use it outside the function.

Comment: the poster have a *GCC* tag in his question

Comment: Why is that so important to you? What is the real use case??

Answer (score 3):

One way to resolve the compiler’s complaint is that you have an unnamed struct that defines no instances is to give it a name:

```
#define CONST_BUG_ON(e)        struct ForDebuggingOnly {int a:!(e);}
```

An alternate way to get the expression testing you want is to declare (but not define) an array that has an illegal size if `e` is true:

```
#define CONST_BUG_ON(e)    extern int ForDebuggingOnly[(e) ? -1 : 1]
```

Comment: If use CONST_BUG_ON several times, this code do not works, gcc complains redefine error.

Comment: @yangwen: Use the second method I showed, the one with `extern int`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a recent GCC compiler, you could use [__builtin_constant_p](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) to test for compile-time constants, perhaps with

```
  #define CONST_BUG_ON(e) do { \
       int tab[__builtin_constant_p(e)?1:-1] = {0}; \
       if (tab[0]) abort(); } while (0)
```

For your question about ignoring some warning, perhaps the [GCC diagnostic pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) could help.

If you want your `CONST_BUG_ON` to work only in declaration contexts, you might try

```
  #define CONST_BUG_ON(e) CONST_BUG_AT(e,__LINE__)
  #define CONST_BUG_AT(e,l) \
     extern int tab_##l[__builtin_constant_p(e)?0:-1];
```

At last you could even customize your GCC compiler (with your specific pragma) perhaps using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (a high-level domain specific language to extend GCC), but that will take you days of work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use macro magic to give yourself a unique ID by passing in the line number

```
#define CONST_BUG_ON_3(e, l) struct buggy##l {int a:!(e);}
#define CONST_BUG_ON_2(e, l) CONST_BUG_ON_3(e, l)
#define CONST_BUG_ON(e) CONST_BUG_ON_2(e, __LINE__)
```

That's fairly icky but it does give a unique name each time it is used (the 2nd level of indirection may be spurious, but this is what I have in some code that has stood the test of time).

Comment: That's good, but still have some problems: If file "a"'s line 6 contain `CONST_BUG_ON(e)`, and file "a" was inclued by file "b", and line 6 of file "b" aslo contains `CONST_BUG_ON(e)`, then gcc complains redefine error. Use `__COUNTER__` instade of __LINE__ may perfect, but my old compiler does not support `__COUNTER__`.

Comment: i think you might have other problems if you have source code set up like that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you try is called a **compile time assertion** or **compile time assert** macro. There are various ways to do this, usually involving arrays with negative dimension when the assertion fails. Many projects call this macro `CT_ASSERT()` and there are [a bunch of Stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=compile%20time%20assert) relating to them.